# Excel VBA - Specify Range as Page Header

Tags: excel, vba

I want to specify a Range as Page Header from my VBA Code.

But when I did

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = HeaderSheet.Range("A1:L2").Value
```

I takes only first cell i.e. A1 from HeaderSheet as Page Header and ignores the rest. Also it doesn't apply border in Page Header.

Any workaround for this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the "Left Header" would be the left-most header for three headers that describe the sheet or report. Normally it would have values such as the report title, author, date of report, etc.

Are you sure you don't mean to indicate the row or column headers?

Below, the PrintTitleRows specifies rows 1 & 2 to be used as rows to repeat at the top. Alternatively columns to repeat on the left side is just the "A" column.

```
Sub example()

    'ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = HeaderSheet.Range("A1:L2").Value

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
       .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$2"
       .PrintTitleColumns = "$A:$A"
    End With
End Sub
```

If you did actually intend to put the contents of cells A1-L2 into the left-most header section then you'll have to do a concatenation of the cells, I believe... viz,

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = Range("a1").Value & " " & Range("b1").Value & " " & Range("a2").Value & " " & Range("b2").Value
End With
```

Comment: @LurinS : PrintTitleRows is what I wanted. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just to add a note. I do believe that the first example is missing an `End With` statement. At least when I use this snippet in my code it is required.

Comment: Adjusted to reflect Christopher's feedback. Thanks